# rx_missed_errors with ring size set to maximum - udp bursts

Tags: vmware-esxi, linux-networking, udp, dropped

Application A sends traffic to B via TCP.
B using multicast (UDP) sends traffic further to C.
Applications on D get this data via TCP.

```
A -> (TCP) -> B -> (UDP) -> C -> (TCP) -> D
```

A - Windows Server
B - Linux VM on ESX host
C - Linux VM on another ESX host (no load - just one vm)
D - Windows clients

When **B** sends traffic to **C** multiple drops can be observed due to the nature of the traffic (bursts) happening on NIC (ixgbe) level (rx_missed_errors directly correspond to what application on **C** observes).

Increasing the size of ring buffer (on **C**) to a maximum value (4096) makes things even worse.

All connections are 10G, traffic levels do not exceed 2Gbit/s (during bursts) (checked using `sar -n DEV 1`).

### Questions:

1. How can I measure bursts with less than 1 second interval?
2. How come increasing the ring size can make things worse?
3. Is there a way of slowing down the traffic on B
   so it can be handled on C without drops at NIC level?
   (Traffic shaping, changing tcp window size/buffer size?)
4. Why if I replace B with a Windows host drops are not happening at all as if udp bursts are shaped in more digestible way.
5. How else could I approach, analyze this problem?

Thanks